# Piping cURL output to FFmpeg doesn't work with mp4 files

Tags: ruby, curl, video, ffmpeg, mp4

I would like to pipe cURL output to FFmpeg the following way in my Ruby script to strip off metadata, chapters and maybe set other metadata too in the future:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
url=ARGV[0]

fname=url.split("/").last
extension=File.extname(fname)
options=""
case extension 
  when /mp4/i
    format="mp4"
    options=" -movflags frag_keyframe+empty_moov "
  when /avi/i
    format="avi"
  when /mkv/i
    format="matroska"
  when /wmv/i
    format="asf"
  else
    format="matroska"
 end

cmd=%Q{ curl -b cookie-file.txt #{url} -L -o - | ffmpeg -y -i - -map 0:v -map 0:a -c:v copy -c:a:0 copy -map_metadata -1 -map_chapters -1 #{options} -f #{format} - | cat > #{fname} }

system cmd
```

When the url (ARGV[0]) points to an .avi, .wmv or .mkv file the script do its job. However when it points to an .mp4 or .mov file it doesn't work, because the input isn't seekable and FFmpeg at first try to read the whole input. When url points to an mp4 file, output to stdout even doesn't work, only when options " -movflags frag_keyframe+empty_moov " is used for the output format. Otherwise I got an error message: "muxer does not support non seekable output". Last cat command is needed because this command pipe will work in a CGI script, and will write its output to STDOUT with appropriate HTTP headers. What options should I use for the input pipe to make my script work with mp4 files too?